# Select each value of ALL inputs on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select every input value with the class 'netSuiteValue' when the submit button is clicked.  Here is what I have so far:

```
$('.netSuiteValue').each(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();
    $('.submitBtn').click(function() {
        $('.theValue').val('all values' + inputValue);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qLPw9/1/

I can not figure out why it is not working.

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen when you click the button, and why are you assigning the handler inside the each statement?

Comment: At the the you are executing this code, both input fields are empty. Hence for each input `inputValue` will be an empty string. You are then binding a click event handler for each input to the submit button, which sets the value to whatever `inputValue` holds at that moment. Your logic is flawed. Instead you should read the values when you click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about it the wrong way. Bind the the click event of the submit button first, then gather your data:

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function() {
    var inputValue;

    $('.netSuiteValue').each(function() {
        inputValue += $(this).val();
    });

    $('.theValue').val('all values' + inputValue);
});​
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/qLPw9/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the value in the loop instead of building up a string.

```
$('.netSuiteValue').each(function() {
    var inputValue = $(this).val();    <--- declare var outside of loop and add to string instead
    $('.submitBtn').click(function() {
        $('.theValue').val('all values' + inputValue);
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

- Your form should be wrapped in a `<form>` tag
- I would attach the event to the form submit instead of submit button click, since you can submit a form with the keyboard as well
- your form inputs should all have unique names

So here's my solution given the above:

```
$('#fieldForm').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var allVals = {};
    $(this).find('input.netSuiteValue').each(function(i, el){
        allVals[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    $('.theValue').val('All values: ' + JSON.stringify(allVals));
});​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qLPw9/15/)

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the name/value pairs, for all of these inputs, that submitting the form through html would give.

```
var values = $('input.netSuiteValue').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
$('.submitBtn').on('click',function(){
    $('.netSuiteValue').each(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/2A6mW/

Answer (score 0):

Because you have the loop outside the submit function. It needs to be inside the submit function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function() {
  var fields = $('.netSuiteValue');
  var values = fields.serialize();
  $('.theValue').val('all values' + values);
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I understood it, with your original code is that you were iterating through the elements and, on each iteration, over-writing the variable with the newer value. And assigning the click event-handler within that loop (which is fairly expensive since, on each iteration, you're (re-)creating an event handler/function.

I'm assuming that you want to iterate through, and retrieve the values of, the input elements in response to clicking the button. So, try instead:

```
// in response to clicking the submit button
$('.submitBtn').click(
    function(){
        // creates variable as an array
        var inputValues = [];
        // iterates through each element returned by the selector
        $('.netSuiteValue').each(
            function(){
                // adds the value of each of those elements to the array
                inputValues.push($(this).val());
            });
        // assigns the value of the .theValue element, and joins the array elements together with commas
        $('.theValue').val('All values: ' + inputValues.join(', '));
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qLPw9/8/).

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Answer (score 0):

I your aim is to show values of all inputs in another input then that might work:

```
$('.submitBtn').click(function() {
    var values = $('.netSuiteValue').map(function(i, e) { 
        return $(e).val(); 
    }).get().join(', ');
    $('.theValue').val('all values: ' + values);
});
```

See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qLPw9/17/).